# Maven build/compile errors, can't find present jar. (Eclipse Scout)

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-scout

I tried to setup a generated HelloWorld [Scout](https://eclipse.org/scout/) application.

Unfortunately I can't get rid off compile errors, which are maven related, moreover this problem occurs only on my local windows machine.

Here is the discussion I had in the Scout forums: [Eclipse Scout Compile Errors](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1086871&goto=1766042&#msg_1766042).

I would appreciate it if s.o. could take a look into it and maybe understand the errors.

I use maven 3.5.0 (tried 3.3.9 too).

Codebase available on [Github](https://github.com/Corrado98/scout-helloworld). (When I clone the project onto another machine and run `mvn clean install` the build succeds. On my current machine it doesn't.)

Comment: what are your maven settings? (see `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml` and `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`)? When you run your build with `-X` you should see in the console output: 
`[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/java/apache-maven-3.0.3/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/myhome/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: Without a pom file or better a link to the project it's hard to say what is causing the issue. Apart from that based on the output I've seen why using flatten-maven-plugin, build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-source etc. ? Is this an OSGi project? Have you tried to run the build from plain command line? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @diginoise the first file you mention is very long, but seems ok (never changed a setting really). The second file points to a local dir and refers also to a artifactory, which should be ok too. 

Yes, I see that debug output too.

Comment: @khmarbaise I could push the project on github if it helps. It seems that my problem only occurs on my machine. This build plugins are needed for the scout sdk to work properly as stated in their official documentation. https://www.eclipse.org/scout/scout_helloworld.html 
This is a multi module maven project and has nothing to do with OSGi.
I tried "mvn clean install" on plain command line. I use maven 3.5.0.

Comment: Pushing on Github could really help...

Comment: @khmarbaise See updated question.

Comment: there have been two updates in the eclipse forum discussion, maybe s.o. can give a hint with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. I deleted again the .m2 folder and redownloaded every dependency.

Compiles perfectly now.